# Issue with code in .spacemacs file on Spacemacs startup

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I have code in the bottom of my `.spacemacs` file to create some keybindings and such related to evil-mode. The code is as follows:

```
;; Evil mode
(use-package evil
  :ensure t
  :config
  (evil-mode 1)

  (use-package evil-escape
    :ensure t
    :config
    (evil-escape-mode 1)
    (setq-default evil-escape-key-sequence "fd")
    (setq-default evil-escape-delay 0.2))

  (use-package evil-leader
    :ensure t
    :config
    (global-evil-leader-mode)
    (evil-leader/set-leader "<SPC>")
    (evil-leader/set-key
      "e" 'find-file
      "bb" 'switch-to-buffer
      "bd" 'kill-buffer-and-window
      "by" 'copy-whole-buffer
      "cy" 'clipboard-kill-ring-save
      "cp" 'clipboard-yank
      "fs" 'save-buffer
      "ms" 'magit-status
      "hs" 'split-window-horizontally
      "iu" 'insert-char
      "lf" 'load-file
      "ne" 'flycheck-next-error
      "pe" 'flycheck-previous-error
      "rm" 'notmuch
      "sm" 'message-send-and-exit
      "si" 'whitespace-mode
      "tn" 'linum-mode
      "tt" 'term
      "w1" 'delete-other-windows
      "wk" 'windmove-left
      "wj" 'windmove-right
      "qq" 'save-buffers-kill-emacs
      "zp" 'zeal-at-point
      )
    )

  (use-package evil-surround
    :ensure t
    :config
    (global-evil-surround-mode))

  (use-package evil-indent-textobject
    :ensure t))
```

For some reason, when I open up Spacemacs with the code in my `.spacemacs` file, I see the following:

[image]

If I remove the code, it opens up correctly, but I can add it back then run `M-x eval-region` and everything works as expected. I am brand new to Spacemacs from Vim so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to import the `evil` package directly. You just need to set the variable `dotspacemacs-editing-style` to `'vim`. Also, any existing packages should be specified in the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` variable. Any packages that don't come with spacemacs can be added via `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` or you could create a layer if they need additional configuration. For more info see the docs here http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#dotfile-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is in between the

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()

)
```

OR

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

)
```

Functions.  There are other ways to get the code evaluated too..

M-x or (SPC SPC) and type

```
configuration-layer/create-layer
```

this will prompt you for title and location etc.. with this you can have many more options